# How to format the number in the python?

Tags: python, format, numbers, integer

the number eleven million one hundred and eleven thousand one hundred and eleven. If you took a pencil in your hand right now, you would write the number like this: 11,111,111, or like this: 11.111.111, or even like this: 11 111 111?

How could I wrote this in python?

Comment: Hardcode it. or if you are trying to do with some exp show your code.

Comment: Do you want to convert number in words to number in numeric format ?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

you mean like this?

```
num =  11111111
print(format (num, ',d')) # 11,111,111
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format with 'f' string python3.5 and above.

```
num = 11111111

print(f'the number is {num}.')
```

Comment: Robin Singh which version are you using.? It works on python3.5 and above. Like I mentioned in the answer. I checked it myself.